# multiple web modules combined as a maven + struts2 project

Tags: java, maven, struts2, web.xml

multiple web modules combined as a maven project.

This is the structure of my project, I want to add one more web module(DCA-web) to my project. DCA-web itself  is a  maven web project. Can I add DCA-web dependency in mian-web pom.xml? since a project cannot have two web.xml how can I implement that? and my projects is also using struts2 how to deal with two `struts.xml`

```
webproject
       |
       --core
       --API
       --main-web
```